# BrunchJS joinTo parent directory (brunch-config.coffee)

Tags: regex, brunch

I would like to get assets from a parent directory in a joinTo like this :

```
exports.config =
  paths:
    public: './../public'
    compass: './config.rb'
    watched: ['app']

  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo: 
        '/js/master.js':/^(../../../directory/target|app[\/\\]public)/
```

My problem come from this `../../../directory/target` to up one or more directory.

But it seem impossible, because BrunchJS use Regex to find directory.

There is a way to do what i wish?

Thanks

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: try using `/^((?:\.\.\/)+directory\/target|app[\/\\]public)/`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question or description of what's going wrong. Or even quite what you're trying to match with that regex - is `app` a sibling of `target`, or local to `cwd`?

But you don't need to use a single regex. You may find it much easier to use a glob pattern or an array of globs/regexes/paths such as

```
files:
  javascripts:
    joinTo: 
      'js/master.js': [
        '../../../directory/target/**/*',
        'app/public/**/*'
      ]
```

Take a look at the [Brunch joinTo documentation](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#files) and [anymatch documentation](https://github.com/es128/anymatch#anymatch-matchers-teststring-returnindex-startindex-endindex).

You also need to watch out for that leading slash in your target file, which may get interpreted as an absolute path.

Comment: I would like to match `target`. So, you resolve my issue. I never seen a configuration (in joinTo) like this, without regex match.. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I haven't solved my problem... I'm sorry
I use this path in path.watched and it doesn't work `'./../../../../*/dynamix/*/assets/public'` 
Same thing in the joinTo `'./../../../../*/dynamix/*/assets/public/**'`

Comment: `'./../../../../*/dynamix/*/assets/public/**'` isn't going to match any files. Perhaps you need to separately describe which paths you are trying to match in order to get help with defining an appropriate glob.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I got an alternative about my first problem..
For my watch i put this `'./../../../../workbench/dynamix/i18n/public/public'` and it work fine
For the joinTo i got an error because once two it's not the good directory.. The main variation is between workbench and vendor but i can use a other alternative..

Comment: My alternative dosen't work... I'm force to use a dynamic path for my project.

Can i make a function (anymatch) to test path or something else? I need to use a `*` into my path.. Ex : `../../../*/path/to/files/**`
Do you have any solution ?

Comment: You need to add the parent dir of the files you might want to compile in `paths.watched`. Then you can use a glob or function in your `joinTo`, but it has to be valid for matching the files you want. Ending a glob in `**` won't match files - to recursively match every file under some dir the glob should end in `**/*`

Comment: Ok sorry for the end `**`. I have understood but the real problem is to match many folder with the next path. GruntJS do this very well.. SO this is not possible ? `../*/path/**/*` (the first star) sorry i'm dumb...